# How to get pid of process with exact name?

Tags: linux

I am trying to get id of process name systemctl stop Myservice but not exact pid through this command

```
   if(0 == system("pidof -x systemctl stop Myservice  > /dev/null")) {
  //A process is running.
   }
```

This code is giving pid of systemctl start Myservice also if it is running in system, need to get specific pid for this process name "systemctl stop Myservice" only?

Comment: `pidof` takes multiple program names, so this looks for any process called `systemctl`, `stop`, **or** `Myservice`. The obvious fix is to quote those three words as one string. However, that is probably *not* the process name: the program name is `systemctl`, and `stop` and `Myservice` are its *arguments*. You may need a specific `ps -o pid,args | grep ...` to achieve this.

Comment: What language is that? PHP? Why are you redirecting the output to `/dev/null`? That's never going to return anything. And why compare it to 0? 0 is a very unlikely output. If that's PHP you probably want to use the second argument to `system` to get the return value. Otherwise you'll just get empty output in every case, which is never identical to 0.

Comment: I was reading it that the `system( )` call of _whatever-language-that-is_ was coming back with the exit code of the executed command.  If it does work in that manner, the approach seems valid, if not the command being run.  If it doesn't work like that, well that is probably a discussion for a different Stack site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If available on your system `pgrep` seems like a good fit here

```
pgrep -xf "systemctl stop Myservice"
```

`pgrep` is provided by the same package as `ps` (at least it is on the CentOS 7 system I referred to)

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides $(which pgrep)
procps-ng-3.3.10-28.el7.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides $(which ps)
procps-ng-3.3.10-28.el7.x86_64
```

Even lightweight distros using BusyBox *seem* to be OK from a narrow test:

```
$ docker run --rm alpine pgrep --help
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-05-09 17:27:12 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: pgrep [-flanovx] [-s SID|-P PPID|PATTERN]
[...]
```

So I would think that if you have `ps` you can rely on `pgrep`, though things could be a bit less certain if your code ends up running inside a container (though this scenario seems pretty unlikely, given what you're attempting to do).

Are you trying to catch the `systemctl stop ...` command in action? This seems like it would be quite prone to race conditions and/or performance issues. What if the C program loops too slowly and misses the command running, or too quickly and consumes excessive CPU?

If your goal is simply to detect when the service leaves `active` state, this approach might be better:

```
systemctl status Myservice | grep -qE "^ +Active: active"
```

This should return a non zero exit code if the service is in anything other than active state.

As per your use case, it might be necessary to only flag when the state changes — rather than every time it sees non-active, via some additional logic.

Comment: pgrep is by default present in os or we need to install some package for it because I need to use ps aux or pidof os commands only.

Comment: If you are constrained in what commands you can use for some reason, please add those details to the question. It will probably be helpful to include information about the underlying OS as well.

Comment: in Linux pgrep is present by default ?

Comment: there are no constrained, just need to verify if this command works in every Linux platform, that's it like ps aux command

Comment: `pgrep` will be on most mainstream (server or desktop) linux distros.  It won't be on tiny distros, which typically use `busybox` to provide very simple implementations of `ps` and many other programs.

Comment: For an exact match, you'd also want to add the `-x` option to `pgrep`. Otherwise, it would match on `oldsystemctl start MyServiceNew` for instance (as it contains `systemctl start MyService`). To get the output of `pgrep`, the OP would also need to use `popen()` instead of `system()`.

Comment: @GauravBaghel answer updated based on comments elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the *process name* is a sequence of 0 to 15 bytes used to name processes. The name of a process changes any time that command executes a command to the first 15 bytes of the basename of the file being executed or when using `pctrl(PR_SET_NAME)` for instance.

That `systemctl stop Myservice` looks more like the concatenation with spaces of 3 arguments passed to `/usr/bin/systemctl` when it was executed by the process or one of its ancestors.

Assuming you want the pids of processes that are currently executing a `/usr/bin/systemctl` that was passed the `systemctl`, `stop` and `Myservice` arguments upon execution, on Linux, the approach would be to:

- do a `stat()` on `/proc/*/exe` files and check that the `st_dev` and `st_ino` are the same as that returned by `stat("/usr/bin/systemctl")` (assuming that `systemd` has not been updated since the process executed `systemctl`).
- and then check that the `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` file for the corresponding process contains `systemctl<NUL>stop<NUL>Myservice<NUL>` (bearing in mind that processes can -- though generally don't -- modify that arbitrarily).

I can't think why you'd want to do that though, especially in a C / C++ program. That looks like an *XY Problem*.

Comment: I am writing a c code if service named My service  is stopped , i have to some specific action , that's why writing a c code, any better solution than this code?

Comment: bxm, I think your comment was intended for @GauravBaghel

Comment: @bxm, at the time of stop action I am seeing the status is like this Active: deactivating (stop), how can I use this thing in c code to check this action

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, apologies, my comment didn’t really belong on your answer, moved into my answer